# Castle Windsor registration by namespace, keyed by name

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm using Windsor as my IoC container. I want to register all of my views in my WPF application in one fell swoop, resolving by type, UserControl and keyed by their view name. Is there a better way than this:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, "MyApp.Views", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    .ToList().ForEach(type => container.Register(Component.For<UserControl>()
    .ImplementedBy(type).Named(type.Name)
    .LifestyleTransient()));
```

I'm not crazy about the string for namespace, and looping through all types in the assembly may not be necessary (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
    container.Register(
        Classes.
.FromAssemblyContaining<OneOfYourView...>()
//.FromThisAssembly()
        .BasedOn<UserControl>()
.Configure(c=>c.LifestyleTransient())
        .Configure(c=>c.Named(c.Implementation.Name))

        .WithServiceSelf() // you can resolve by Type
        );
```

Comment: This answer doesn't register the UCs by name, nor does it specify a namespace. I've moved to resolving by type, but I'm still targeting specific namespaces with a string.

Comment: Edits should fit your needs. You may consider FromDirectory in order to scan the whole bin

Answer (score 0):

To improve it a bit, you can replace:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
```

by:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes()
```

So private types are not included in the mix.

Secondly, you do not have a type check in your query, so any class could be registered (even abstract classes or interfaces).

```
 Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
 .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract 
     && typeof(UserControl).IsAssignableFrom(t) 
     && t.Namespace.StartsWith("MyApp.Views", StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToList();
```

This will add some more safety guards to make sure only types which can be resolved as UserControl can be registered.

(Please Note I added: StarstWith instead of Equals, since it can also help having better sub folder/sub namespaces hierarchy, but that is situational).

Last, since you use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),

This means that your application depends on your container, moving the registration/resolve to a dedicated assembly is a recommended practice.